# Unit sphere is sequentially compact \ compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

If $V$ is a liniar space and $dimV=n$ finite, then the set $ S=\{x \in V;\|x\|_1=1\}  $ is bounded and closed .And from Heine Borel theorem $S$ will be compact.$$ $$ My question: Is there a way to show a sequence from $S$ have a convergent subsequence? $$$$
If not how to proof $S$ is closed and bounded?

Comment: Compactness implies limit point compactness. Limit point compactness implies sequential compactness provided the space is first countable and Hausdorff. In your case the sphere is a subspace of Euclidean space which is second countable(so it is first countable) and Hausdorff therefore it is sequentially compact.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a sequence in S with no convergent subsequence in S. Then for each x in S there is a open neighborhood containing no points in the sequence except x. S is in the union of all these open neighborhoods. Because of S being compact, there exists a finite subcover. However at least one of these finite sets covering S has to contain infinite elements of the sequence in contradiction to our choice of the open neighborhoods.

Comment: Let S be any compact set and it still works.

Comment: ok ...I have wrongly formulated the question sorry. My intention is to proof S is sequential compact without know is compact. Or to proof is closed and bounded PS:sorry for my english.

Comment: if i say $x_n $ is a sequence from $\mathbb R^n$ and is bounded because $\|x\|_1=1 $. $=>$ bounded on components and because components are from $ \mathbb R$ => convergence on componets=>$x_n$ is convergent $$ $$ that will be correct?(we know that: $\mathbb R^n \cong V$)